# Meteor router for multiple layouts to use different layout for home

Tags: javascript, meteor, url-routing, iron-router

How to inherit the iron:router on only "homepage"... like whenever visitors visit the website...i'd like the different look without using nav bar.All other pages i want nav bar.but only for home ,i don't.So how do you inherit the use of iron:router only for 1 page?
Can we do like this?

```js
Router.configure({
 layoutTemplate: 'main'
});
Router.route('/',  {
template: 'TEMPLATENAME',
layoutTemplate: 'home'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [Meteor Routing and Layout](https://www.codetutorial.io/meteor-routing-and-layout/)

```
Router.configure({
  // the default layout
  layoutTemplate: 'mainNav'
});

Router.route('/', function () {
  this.render('firstPage');
  this.layout('mainNav');
});    

Router.route('/second', function () {
  this.render('secondPage');
  this.layout('mainNav');
});
```

You should be able to set up multiple layouts and just specificy the page and the corresponding layout you want for it.

EDIT: My first response was WAY off, sorry about that.